# Array field not being posted to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have the following Javascript object which when I post to Mongo gets submitted correctly, apart from the photos field, which doesn't get submitted at all. What is causing this please?

This is a console log of the form object to be posted:

```
createdAt: 1630072305502
photos: 
    0: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
    1: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
post: "sample text"
userId: "1iNGV..."
```

I just use an axios post to send the form data to the api endpoint:

```
axios.post('/api/posts', form)
```

This is the basic api endpoint code:

```
case 'POST':
    await db.collection("posts").insertOne(req.body);
    res.json({
        status: "ok",
        message: "Post added"
    })
    break;
```

Can anyone see why the 'photos' field is always empty/blank in Mongo, while the others are fine?

EDIT: This is a log of the req.body - the photo array is empty, which I don't understand as a log of the object before it's sent has the photo array populated.

```
req body:  {
    userId: '...',
    post: 'some text',
    createdAt: 1630114254432,
    photos: [],
    _id: new ObjectId("612991db457c70d18953d5ae")
}
```

Comment: Try logging both req.body and the result of the insertOne

Comment: Cheers, Joe, I don't know why I didn't check that. I've edited the question with the results of the log - the photo array is empty in the req.body

Comment: Can you check the request payload in the Network tab of DevTools?

Comment: Hi @HandsomeCoder, ah, it's empty. Do you know why that is?

Comment: To clarify my last comment, the 'photos' array is empty - every other field is populated

Comment: Need to check the input from where you are getting the data for `photos`... can you share that code?

Comment: It's a file input that accepts multiple files. on form submit these then get sent off to Firebase Storage and Firebase sends back the file URL for each file. The photos array in the form object is then populated with these URLs. This is working, as you can see the file urls in the first code sample. I just can't get that photos array into Mongo. I'll try manually uploading data in this structure just to see what happens